# Average squared distance between two samples of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I have a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. I draw twice from it, and get the values $X_1$ and $X_2$. What's $E\left[(X_1 - X_2)^2\right]$?

More generally, for what $f$ is there a closed form solution to $E\left[f(X_1 - X_2)\right]$?

Comment: Presuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are drawn independently, which I presume id your intention. then $X_1-X_2$ is distributed as a Normal with mean 0 and variance 2. Therefore the expectation of its square equals its variance + square of its mean, so equals 2.

Comment: Hey Mark, it seems to be (empirically) equal to 2. I think that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo which was already corrected by the time your comment posted. As to your question on what f has a closed form solution, you might as well just put that in terms of which f has closed form for $E(f(X_1)$. That's a little arbitrary, because for any f for which the expectation exists, we can define a function, now considered to be a closed form solution, as its value.

Comment: If you meant to say that the draws are independent, you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What would it mean for two draws from a normal distribution to not be independent?

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of differences between two samples from a normal distribution with mean 0 is the same as the distribution of sums.

The [sum of two independent normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) with mean 0 and variance 1 is a random variable distributed according to a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 2.

So the answer is 2.

Because this difference is just a normal distribution, you could calculate this for any other function $f$ whose expectation value over a normal distribution has a closed form.

Comment: @Glen_b: what do you think of my edit?